# Alocação Dinâmica de char com ponteiros

Tags: c

Sou iniciante em C e tenho uma questão que não estou conseguindo resolver da forma como gostaria e queria saber o porque disso.

Contextualizando, tenho que fazer uma corrida que troque as posições numa array, exemplificando: 
1° L...
2° .L..
3° ..L.
4° ...L

Minha ideia era que a array inicialize com corrida[3] = "L" e o resto da array seja preenchida com os pontos automaticamente com um laço e pra isso usei um ponteiro, mas não esta funcionando como eu esperava e sempre da esse erro: 
"warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

O código que estou tentando fazer é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{    
int corridaTart = 0, corridaLebre = 0;
char posicaoTart[70] = "L";
char posicaoLebre[70] = "T";
char *ponteiroTart = posicaoTart;
char *ponteiroLebre = posicaoLebre;
int randNumeroTart;
int randNumeroLebr;
srand(time(NULL));

printf("%c", *ponteiroLebre);

for (int i = 1; i < 70; i++)
{
    *(ponteiroLebre+i) = ".";
    ++ponteiroLebre;

}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf(" %c ", *(ponteiroLebre+1));
}
return 0;
}
```

Outro que tentei fazer com struct foi assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
struct corrida
{
    int corrida;
    char posicao[70];
    int rand;
};
struct corrida lebre, *ponteiro;
struct corrida tart, *ponteiro2;
srand(time(NULL));

ponteiro = &lebre;
ponteiro2 = &tart;
ponteiro->posicao[0] = "L";
ponteiro2->posicao[0] = "T";

for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
{
    ponteiro->posicao[i] = ".";
    printf("%c",lebre.posicao[i]);
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não confunda aspas duplas ("), delimitador de uma string, com aspas simples ('), delimitador de um caractere. Para atribuir uma caractere você utiliza o operador `=` mas para string deve utilizar a função strcpy de <string.h>.  Não tem muito sentido este loop em que você pega o conteúdo de um endereço acrescido do valor da variável de controle do loop e logo a seguir incrementa o endereço, sempre estará pulando posições de seu array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No primeiro programa tu escreveste dois laços, o primeiro tu tentaste desenhar a pista, de comprimento de 70 caracteres, que é equivalente ao laço abaixo (tomei a liberdade de substituir as aspas por apóstrofos):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 70; i++)
{
    ponteiroLebre[i] = '.';
    ++ponteiroLebre;

}
```

O que está acontecendo aqui é que o ponteiro avança uma posição, e é acrescido por `i`, em outras palavras, um ponto está sendo escrito numa posição, em outra não. A escrita de dados na memória vai além do que está alocado (provavelmente até a posição 139) e o sistema operacional não deixa isso acontecer, fechando o programa. Para corrigir isso, basta apagar a linha onde o ponteiro é incrementado:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 70; i++)
{
    ponteiroLebre[i] = '.';

}
```

No segundo laço, o valor em `ponteiroLebre[1]` é escrito dez vezes, com um espaço na frente e outro atrás, ou seja, dois espaços de distância entre os caracteres representado pelo caractere contido no `ponteiroLebre[1]`.

No segundo programa, tu escreveste apenas um laço, ele vai escrever a pista na memória, porém tens de substituir as aspas pelos apóstrofos. Não ficou suficientemente claro o que tu queres fazer, mas ofereço-lhe esse pequeno programa que executa as partes que funcionam no teu programa, pode ser que lhe ajude a pensar melhor em como escrevê-lo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COMPRIMENTO_DA_PISTA 70
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        char pista[COMPRIMENTO_DA_PISTA];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < COMPRIMENTO_DA_PISTA; i++)
                pista[i] = '.';
        pista[COMPRIMENTO_DA_PISTA - 1] = '\0';
        for (size_t i = 1; i < COMPRIMENTO_DA_PISTA; i++) {
                pista[i - 1] = 'L';
                printf("%s\n", pista);
                pista[i - 1] = '.';
        }
        putchar('\n');
        return 0;
}
```